# How to copy std::regex_token_iterator to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl

The code below fails to copy values from regex_token_iterator to a std::vector; Visual Studio 2015 reports that 'std::copy' with parameters may be unsafe.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    // String to split in words
    std::string line = "dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4";

    // Split the string in words
    std::vector<std::string> to_vector;
    const std::regex ws_re("\\\\"); 
    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), ws_re, -1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string>>(to_vector));

    // Display the words
    std::cout << "Words: ";
    std::copy(begin(to_vector), end(to_vector), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: I don't know for sure whether it's related, but you're giving a vector to a function that expects iterators.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will search how to pass an insert forward iterator on the vector.

Comment: Your vector is empty. You have to use a back_inserter.

Comment: You also have to correct `ws_re("\\")`, it should be `ws_re("\\\\")`.

Comment: Sorry of my inexperience with std. The following fails with type 'unknown-type' unexpected.  Can someone give me a direction on what's wrong?   std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), ws_re, -1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::string>>(to_vector));

Comment: Which compiler/version? The code as shown compiles and runs fine in VS 2017 and clang 5. No L3 or L4 warnings.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 (I will edit the question to mention it)

Comment: It looks the problem was the settings using MFC and stdafx.h. I am sorry for my misunderstanding. The code compiles fine with VS2015 Level 5.

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution to store the values extracted by regex_token_iterator to a vector:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s("dir1\\dir2\\dir3\\dir4");

    // Split the line in words
    const std::regex reg_exp("\\\\");
    const std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> end_tokens;
    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> it(s.begin(), s.end(), reg_exp, -1);
    std::vector<std::string> to_vector;
    while (it != end_tokens)
    {
        to_vector.emplace_back(*it++);
    }

    // Display the content of the vector
    std::copy(begin(to_vector), 
              end(to_vector), 
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old code but as i was also looking for a solution. It is very simple the third parameter should be back_inserter to vector.

```
std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), ws_re, -1),
          std::sregex_token_iterator(),
          std::back_inserter(to_vector));
```